# Windows XP computer isolated in the Workgroup

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, sharing

At home I've got a central server with Windows 8.1 on it with some shared folders (hostname \SERVER).
I also have two Windows 10 PCs that exange files with the server successfully and they also share folders. Then the fourth machine with Win XP cannot map other PCs folders, or better it cannot resolve hostnames, even pinging them. Also other computers cannot connect to XP. 
I tried these solutions:
1. Disable Password Protected sharing on server.
2. Verify Workgroups, and they are the same.
3. Disable Xp Firewall and AVG Internet Security.
4. Reset XP Winsock.
5. Flush Xp dns cache.
6. Reset credential manager.
7. Reset XP TCP-IP settings.
8. Set Folder permissions to Everyone on server

But nothing worked. Internet connection is working well on XP.

Comment: Where is your XP machine getting DNS from? Can you ping the 8.1 PC base on IP?

Comment: Tell us what the IP address of the Windows 8.1 is, what the IP address of the Windows 10 machines are, and the IP address of the Windows XP machine. Perhaps these are on different subnets and that's the issue. From command line on each PC (elevated with administrator RUNAS) run the `IPCONFIG /ALL` command and tell what each machine's IP Address is set to from the interface which each use to access Internet as you state all are working well.

Comment: Ips are: 192.168.1.12 for Xp, 192.168.1.100 for the server. Same subnet. I can ping the direct ip address of the server from xp but not the hostname (getting "cannot resolve" error)

Comment: Are they all on DHCP? or STATIC, or a bit of both? What's the DNS server you're using on the XP machine? Is it the same for the other machines? If not, I suggest using the same DNS (internal), or you will have to edit host files or come up with other ways to have the hostname resolve to the IP you want.